# Reliable method for creating a Sharepoint List from LARGE Excel Table

Tags: excel, sharepoint-list

I've tried two separate methods for creating a Sharepoint list from a LARGE Excel table.

Both have failed.

**What is a reliable method for creating such a list?**

**Specifics:**

- Excel file size: 16.123 MB
- ~460k records
- File consists only of the given data (as a table using `Insert/Table/My Table has Headers`)

**Tried:**

- From Sharepoint, `Add App/Import from Excel` using Internet Explorer

  - **Results**: At ~172k records, process stops. Excel freezes, IE freezes
- From Excel, `Export to Sharepoint list` option

  - **Results:** At ~170k records, process stops. Excel says "List successfully created...".
  - Obviously less than half the records were actually created.

**What is the best way forward here?**

Thank you

Comment: Better way to accheive this functionality, to write a custom code to create a list from Excel large list .

Comment: @RajkiranSwain, do you have an example?